# Can I put an ngIf else condition on a Angular Material table?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I've followed the Angular docs here https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf to create an NgIf else conditional over my Material Table. It is reading remote JSON file as API.

The API is twitter data and one of the fields I want to run condition on is 'replies'. If there are no replies, I want to replace the "0" with a "-".

I am getting the error

> Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute prefixed with * ("  Replies 
>         ]*ngIf="hashtags.replies<1; else noReplies"> {{hashtags.replies}} 
>         "):`

***So it seems I cannot run NgIf and interpolate my data in the same element, I've tried all kinds of combinations in the HTML but I am real stuck.***

**HTML**

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="replies">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Replies </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let hashtags" *ngIf="hashtags.replies<1; else noReplies"> {{hashtags.replies}} </td>
  <ng-template #noReplies>-</ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="replies">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Replies </th>
      <ng-container *matCellDef="let hashtags">
        <td mat-cell *ngIf="(hashtags.replies>0); else noReplies"> {{hashtags.replies}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-template #noReplies>-</ng-template>
    </ng-container>
```

The reason for getting this error is because your **can't put 2 structural directives on the same DOM**

In your code, you were using `*matCellDef` and `*ngIf` on the same `<td>`.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I had to rework your code suggestion a bit (reverse the order of `let hashtags` and 'nfIf` because it was complaining about empty variable for "reples". Also my logic was flawed. I changed the condition to `ngIf="(hashtags.replies>0); else noReplies"`

Comment: @RyanCoolwebs : Cool, but i hope it helped you as an answer  and get the idea. My bad that i missed that part

Answer (score 2):

you can do it this way...... xd

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="estadoRevision">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Revision</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <td *ngIf="element.a === 0"> ejemplo </td>
        <td *ngIf="element.a === 1"> ejemplo </td>
    </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't do the conditional directly in the interpolation?

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let hashtags">{{hashtags.replies > 0 ? hashtag.replies : '-'}}</td>
```