# ngSwitch causing property does not exist on type error

Tags: angular

I am filling a Material Data Table with data from an API and want to change a cell depending on the text in *powershell.Status* but using [ngSwitch] is causing the following error:

> Error:
> src/app/shared/components/rsio-table/rsio-table.component.html:16:38 -
> error TS2339: Property 'powershell' does n ot exist on type
> 'RsioTableComponent'.
>
> 16             <ng-container [ngSwitch]=powershell.Status>
> ~~~~~~~~~~
>
> src/app/shared/components/rsio-table/rsio-table.component.ts:9:16
> 9   templateUrl: './rsio-table.component.html',
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> Error occurs in the template of component RsioTableComponent.

Without the switch statement the the text in powershell.Status is displayed correctly.

rsio-table.component.html:

```
   <div>
        <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z3">
    
            <ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let powershell">{{powershell.Name}}</mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
    
            <ng-container matColumnDef="Description">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Description</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let powershell">{{powershell.Description}}</mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
    
            <ng-container matColumnDef="Status">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Status</mat-header-cell>
                <ng-container [ngSwitch]="powershell.Status">
                    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'Running'">
                        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let powershell">{{powershell.Status}}</mat-cell>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>Something else</ng-container>
                </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
    
            <ng-container matColumnDef="options">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Options</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let powershell">
                    <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu">
                        <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
    
            <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
            <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns" class="table-row"></mat-row>
    
        </mat-table>
    </div>
    
    <mat-menu #appMenu="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item>Restart</button>
    </mat-menu>
```

rsio-table.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PowershellService } from 'src/app/services/powershell.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { powershell } from 'src/app/models/powershell.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-rsio-table',
  templateUrl: './rsio-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./rsio-table.component.scss']
})
export class RsioTableComponent implements OnInit {

  dataSource = new PowerShellDataSource(this.powershellService);
  displayedColumns = ['Name', 'Description', 'Status', 'options'];

  constructor(private powershellService: PowershellService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}


export class PowerShellDataSource extends DataSource<any> {

  constructor(private powershellService: PowershellService) {
    super();
  }

  connect(): Observable<powershell[]> {
    return this.powershellService.getPowershell();
  }

  disconnect() { };
}
```

How can I properly use the ngSwitch to check the text of powershell.Status?

**UPDATE:** With the help of the accepted answer I made it work. This is how I did it in the end:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="Status">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Status</mat-header-cell>
    <ng-container *matCellDef="let powershell">
        <mat-cell [ngSwitch]="powershell.Status">
            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'Running'">
                <mat-chip-list>
                    <mat-chip class="running" selected>Running</mat-chip>
                </mat-chip-list>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'Stopped'">
                <mat-chip-list>
                    <mat-chip class="stopped" selected>Stopped</mat-chip>
                </mat-chip-list>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>
                <mat-chip-list>
                    <mat-chip>{{powershell.Status}}</mat-chip>
                </mat-chip-list>
            </ng-container>
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: can you add `ngSwitch` part from html, so that it will be clear to check the error cause..

Comment: I made a formatting error, should be fixed now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue seems to be not with **`ngSwitch`** but the way you are accessing the *mat-cell* data.

```
     <ng-container [ngSwitch]="powershell.Status">
         <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'Running'">
             <mat-cell *matCellDef="let powershell">{{powershell.Status}}</mat-cell> // powershell object can only accessible here but not outside of this tag
         </ng-container>
     <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>Something else</ng-container>
```

You can not access ***powershell*** variable out of `<mat-cell>` tag, if required any condition we need to do this inside of it.

These links might be useful

- https://github.com/angular/components/issues/16273
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/57242163/9764133

Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: That clears up why it is not working, any idea on how to work around it? I have read the linked questions before posting mine, but did not find any answers. If I can only put the condition inside <mat-cell> but I can only have one structural directives on same DOM, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: have you tried second link answer, you can take that as reference and replace it with `ngSwitch` as per your requirement

Comment: I had to tweak it a bit but made it work in the end. thanks!